# c# Passing an object to a REST enabled WCF Service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to pass a custom object and 2 string values to a WCF service that has REST and SOAP enabled

below is the service contract

```
[OperationContract]
     [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/AddData/{Name}/{Id}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped )]
           bool AddData(CustomData itm,string Name, string Id);
```

then I have sample code to try call the service using HTTP Client , the issue I have is that the string values get passed in but the object value is null

Im not sure if I have defined the service wrong or calling the service wrong ?

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
 var client = new HttpClient();
            var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:52309/Service1.svc/rest/AddData/test/1");

            CustomData data = new  CustomData ();
            data.description = "TEST";
            data.fieldid = "test1";
            data.fieldvalue = "BLA";

            string postBody = JsonSerializer(data);

            HttpContent contentPost = new StringContent(postBody , Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage wcfResponse = await client.PostAsync(uri, contentPost).ContinueWith((postTask) => postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode());


            client.Dispose();
 string responJsonText = await wcfResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

 }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
}

public string JsonSerializer(FormsData  objectToSerialize)
    {
        if (objectToSerialize == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("objectToSerialize must not be null");
        }
        MemoryStream ms = null;

        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
        ms = new MemoryStream();
        serializer.WriteObject(ms, objectToSerialize);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
        return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Comment: Is the message body supposed to contain `CustomData` formeatted as JSON? If so, the type needs to be `Stream` then you deserialise it that way.

Comment: Yes I think im trying to format the object as JSON, would you mind elaborating a bit  , where abouts does the type need to be stream ?

Comment: Have you looked at using [`PostAsJsonAsync<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944521%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)?

Comment: I get the same issue      HttpResponseMessage wcfResponse = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:52309/Service1.svc/rest/AddData/test/1", data);

Comment: Basically WCF has no idea where to pull the `CustomData` argument from. What it received is simply a message with a parameterised URL, and a body, which is included as a `Stream` if the first argument is of that type. What you need to do is receive the message body as a stream, read it, then reverse the `JsonSerializer` done on the client.

Comment: Unless of course the `CustomData` object has some sort of deserialisation step, such as a `DataContract`.

Comment: so are you saying I cant use bool AddData(CustomData itm,string Name, string Id); that I have to use  bool AddData(Stream itm,string Name, string Id);

Comment: any chance you could give me a basic code sample ?

Comment: @RachaelM sorry, I meant to link [`PostAsync<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj614376(v=vs.118).aspx) which lets you post the object directly without having to first convert to Json.

Comment: thanks @DavidG but doesn't seem to work either for me   `await client.PostAsJsonAsync("test/5233", data);`  but the value is still passed in as null

Comment: I resolved the issue by adding `[DataContract(Namespace = "FormsData")]` and `[DataMember(Name = "formName")]` to each variable in the class definition and then called it using `PostAsJsonAsync` and passing the object directly. Thanks @DanielPark and @DavidG for the pointers in the right direction

Comment: Good to hear you got it solved!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by adding 
`[DataContract(Namespace = "CustomData")]` and `[DataMember(Name = "fieldvalue")]`  to each variable in the class definition and then called it using PostAsJsonAsync and passing the object directly. Thanks @DanielPark and @DavidG for the pointers in the right direction